Azure Static Web App sleeps / cold start even with premium standard tier
I'm hosting a Vue3 application on Azure Static Web Apps, but I've noticed that after a period of inactivity, the initial page load becomes noticeably slow, almost like a cold start or sleep mode activation. Once loaded, the app performs well, but this slowdown returns after a period of inactivity.
Is there a way to prevent this and reduce the initial page load time? I’ve tried using Uptime Robot to "ping" the app, and here are the response times observed:


Does response time look the same in network tab in a browser? It should start with initial page load. At this point it's not related to Vue at all

I don't think it's related to Vue at all, it has something to do with the Azure Static Web app. For context I provided that I've used Vue to create the app.

I've setup UptimeRobot to ping my app every 5 minutes, this seems to work. Although if anyone knows a different solution, let me know.
